# How do I measure disk space occupied by a Postgres index?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, storage

I’m using Postgres 9.5.1 on Mac Sierra.  I have created the following index on my table

```
CREATE INDEX my_object_times_name_gin_trgm_idx 
ON my_object_times USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops);
```

How do I measure how much disk space this index takes up on disk?  I want to compare this to the space that would be sued if I create another type of index.  Note that I don’t care about the size of the data in the table, only the storage occupied by the index.

Comment: The simplest way to do this is actually `\di+ [index name]`, whereas the brackets denote that the name of index is an optional argument (shows all indices if omitted).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [`pg_relation_size()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBOBJECT) for that, e.g:

```
select pg_relation_size('my_object_times_name_gin_trgm_idx');
```

The size is in bytes. If you want that formatted in a "human readable" way, you can use `pg_size_pretty()`

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('my_object_times_name_gin_trgm_idx'));
```

Comment: ```sql
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pg_relation_size"
LINE 1: pg_relation_size('IDX_xxxx');
```

I'm getting this error

Answer (score 1):

You'll find some interesting scripts here: [Disk Usage](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage)

```
SELECT d.datname AS Name,  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) AS Owner,
    CASE WHEN pg_catalog.has_database_privilege(d.datname, 'CONNECT')
        THEN pg_catalog.pg_size_pretty(pg_catalog.pg_database_size(d.datname))
        ELSE 'No Access'
    END AS SIZE
FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d
    ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN pg_catalog.has_database_privilege(d.datname, 'CONNECT')
        THEN pg_catalog.pg_database_size(d.datname)
        ELSE NULL
    END DESC -- nulls first
    LIMIT 20
```